# Telnet display attributes issue

Tags: telnet, telnetlib, displayattribute

I try to implement a Telnet client,

I can understand simple rule like:

(ESC)[41m => set background color to red

(ESC)[32;41m => set background color to red, font color to green

but I'm confused for something, like this:

(ESC)[;36

(ESC)[;36;46m

(ESC)[1;30;44m

what's the mean ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I try the code on ANSI Editor,

looks like it doesn't really matter has a value beofre ";" or not,

just follow the display attribute rule.

(ESC)[;36 => set font color to Cyan

(ESC)[;36;46m => set font color to Cyan, background color to Cyan

(ESC)[1;30;44m => set font to Bright, font color to Black, background color to Blue

http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#colors